# What is a private building?

Tags: tropico-4

I've received an offer to purchase all of the private buildings on my island.  Unfortunately, I have no idea what constitutes a private building, and just accepting the offer didn't seem to net me anything.  So what is a private building?  Do I have to designate them somehow?  Is there a downside to selling them like this?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Private buildings are buildings that are not owned by you -- you can't set the wages or working conditions, and you don't receive any profits from them aside from a monthly rent. You are expected to make sure it's supplied with sufficient manpower and resources; if it fails to make a profit, it gets torn down.

You can get offers for private buildings if you have a Stock Exchange and either an economy minister or a foreign minister (I think; not sure about the ministers)